# GetObject() 429 Error When Using PSExec To Run WScript File On Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, excel, vbscript, com, psexec

I am using the following PSExec command to run a WScript file on a VMware Player 7 virtual machine:

```
psexec \\devtest1 -u "Administrator" -p "password" -h -i 1 -d c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe c:\scripts\closefiles.vbs
```

This PSExec command runs the closefiles.vbs file on the virtual machine DEVTEST1.  When run, the closefiles.vbs file is supposed to detect any open instance of Excel 2007 and, if found, save every open workbook, then close each workbook.  When run locally on the virtual machine, closefiles.vbs executes perfectly.

The problem arises when I use PSExec from a remote machine to execute the closefiles.vbs file on the virtual machine.  Windows 7 has locked down UAC remote access to prevent loopback attacks.  For security reasons, I must keep this restriction in place (I DO know how to change the registry to remove the UAC remote access restriction).  This means that the only account that I can use to run any application on the virtual machine, without using the Remote Desktop Client (which I can't use in this application), is the virtual machine's Administrator account.

When I run closefiles.vbs on the virtual machine using PSExec and the virtual machine's Administrator account and password from the remote machine it gives me a 429 error when it encounters the following statement:

```
Set objXL = GetObject( , "Excel.Application")
```

This ALWAYS happens when the PSExec command is run against the virtual machine when any user other than the Administrator is logged on at the virtual machine.  But when the Administrator is logged on at the virtual machine, the closefiles.vbs file executes perfectly.  Why does the closefiles.vbs work when the virtual machine's Administrator is logged on and not when any other virtual machine user is logged on?  How can I fix this problem?  Here's the closefiles.vbs code:

```
Option Explicit
'--------------------------------------------------

'*** Dimension Local Variables ***
Dim objXL, i

'*** Enable Error Handling ***
On Error Resume Next

'*** Set Excel Object Variable ***
Set objXL = GetObject( , "Excel.Application")

'*** Trap Error And Shutdown Computer If No Open Excel Workbooks ***
If Err.Number > 0 Then 'No open Excel workbooks
 MsgBox ("ErrorLevel ... " & Err.Number)
 Wscript.quit
End If

'*** Save Data And Close Each Open Excel Workbook ***
For Each i In objXL.Workbooks 'Close each open Excel workbook
 i.Save
 i.Close
Next
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Double-check the session number that the interactive user is logged onto, i.e., the `-i 1` in the psexec command line.  Task Manager can show you session numbers via the Select Columns option.  But I wouldn't be surprised if COM can only find existing Excel.Application objects that are associated with the same user that is making the call.

Comment: I didn't include this in my original post, but I am using qwinsta to query the virtual machine and return its active user session number to the PSExec command as the variable %id% (both the qwinsta and PSExec are present in the same .cmd file that is run from the remote machine against the virtual machine).  I wanted to keep my original post as simple as I could.  I know the session number is working interactively because I can successfully display a WScript shell.popup message on the virtual machine.  Is there some way that COM wouldn't "see" a session number that works interactively?

Comment: If the script can display a message to the user, it is running in the correct session, so that isn't your problem.  It seems more likely that COM, or the Office COM objects, are enforcing a separation between different user accounts.  However, it might still be something to do with psexec.  To eliminate that possibility, try logging into the VM as the other user and then using "run as" to run the script in the context of the Administrator account.  I suspect you'll find that doesn't work, either.

Comment: Possible workaround: write a script or program that runs in the context of the user, in the background (e.g., launched via the Startup folder) and does the work on your behalf when triggered.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using runas on a remote machine.  So I created a task in Task Scheduler on the virtual machine.  I used the Administrators Group when I created the task so that I didn't have that as a possible permissions issue.  Then I ran the task from an administrative command prompt on the virtual machine using schtasks.  When I was logged into the virtual machine as Administrator I didn't get the 429 error.  But when I was logged in as any other user who is a member of the Administrators Group, I got the 429 error.  This feels like a permissions issue.  Suggestions?

Comment: By "using run as" I meant: log into the virtual machine as the non-admin user, click on the Start Menu, type "cmd", press CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER, put in the Administrator username and password, then run the script from that command window, i.e., `wscript.exe c:\scripts\closefiles.vbs`.  Using the Task Scheduler is another unnecessary complication. :-)

Comment: But the bottom line is that I think that Office simply won't let you do that.  You can manipulate your own Office processes, but not somebody elses.

Comment: Thanks, Harry, for staying with me on this thread.  I will be trying your suggestion today and will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harry, your observation about Office not allowing one user to manipulate another user's processes appears to be my problem.  I even tried "decoupling" the closefiles.vbs files from UAC permissions by trying to use Task Scheduler to run closefiles.vbs using an event trigger.  That didn't work because Task Scheduler is also integrated with UAC.  I've opened a new question on StackOverflow to see if there is another approach to saving open Excel file in a shutdown triggered by a power outage (the application of the closefiles.vbs script) at

> Save & Close Open Excel 2007 Files Automatically BEFORE Shutdown Due
>   To Power Loss